# Using querySelectorAll, how can I catch the attributes in some cases and the whole element in other cases?

Tags: node.js, css-selectors, innertext

Using node and having something similar to this:

```
const carsforsale = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(div > p, div > a, div> div > h1))
return carsforsale.map(elem => elem.innerText)
```

Let's say I wanted to catch the innerText from `<p>` and `<h1>` but not from `<a>`, since I just want the href attribute from `<a>` and the innerText will be returned as well when the map function is used, filling the array with unnecessary information.

Is there an easy way to do this on the query selector function?

Or even an easy way of doing it on the map function?

Comment: So you'd want a result of something like `['foo', 'bar', '/someurl']`, for two `<p>`s (or `<h1>`s) followed by an `a`, is that it? A concrete example of your input and expected output would significantly clarify the question

Comment: Exactly, that's the result I want, something like : `['Audi A5 2017', '$25.000', '/linktotheaudi']`
Code is looking like this (node + puppeteer)

    await page.goto('https://www.carsales.com.au/cars/audi/?area=Stock&vertical=car&WT.z_srchsrcx=makemodel')
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const ahref = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a.list-link, div > ul > li > a > div > div > h2, div > ul > li > a > div > p, div > ul > li > a > div > div > p"))
    return ahref.map(h2 => h2.innerText)
  });
console.log(data);}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow MDW, please add a bit more context to the question, as mentioned by CertainPerformance, the expected output would help people understand your need. See more in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, @lucascaro, I've added some context. I think my question was already minimal but the lack of context made it incomplet but I guess it attended to the "veriafiable" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Array.from` accepts a second argument, which is a mapper function - whenver you have an `Array.from` followed by a `.map`, you can condense that into a single `Array.from`.

Inside the mapper function, you just need to check the `tagName` of the element you're iterating over:

```
return Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('div > p, div > a, div> div > h1'),
  elem => (
    elem.tagName === 'A' ? elem.href : elem.innerText
  )
);
```

Also note that when you use strings, they need to be enclosed in delimiters such as `'`, `"`, or `` ` ``. (`document.querySelectorAll(div > p, div > a, div> div > h1)` will result in a `SyntaxError`)

A side note, you *probably* want `textContent` instead of `innerText`. `innerText` is a [quirky, harder to use](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) version of `textContent` in most cases.

Comment: Thank you!! That was what I wanted and then some more. I'm new to javascript and have never even used a simple conditional. Also, i've never expected to be so easy to use one directly into the `map` function. 
I went and read a little bit more about `Array.from` and the `map` functions.
I can't give points for answers cause my account is new here, but man, those 60k points of reputation are well deserved :)